# If my server requests makes a post request to a URL what information does that server receive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

If I have a domain. `www.mydomain.com` And it's running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using `Elastic Load Balancer` which points it to multiple EC2 servers to use. And I request information from a 3rd party server.

What information will they see?
Will they see that it came from `www.mydomain.com` or will they just see the EC2 ip address? Would they be able to see any information on the Elastic Load Balancer?

I'm guessing no since the domain points to ELB which then delegates the request to an EC2. So I'm assuming the EC2 doesn't send any information relating to the domain or ELB. But am unsure. Could anybody provide some more info on this possibly?

Edit: Would a VPC affect anything here?

Comment: just to confirm you are sending some request from ec2 via load balancer  to some 3 party server?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra So I'm not certain if the request comes from the load balancer or ec2. It makes a request and gets a response. I assume it comes from the EC2 since that's where the processing happens. But I'm unsure if the EC2 passes anything back to the load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html) talk about request header which are automatically added by load balancer.

though they did not mention anything about response header, but whatever i got from.

> There should be no need to worry about the ELB leaking the origin information.
> However, the webserver and AP server on EC2 may put their own information back into cookies, custom headers, and so on.
> Use Browser developer tools or You can use the curl command to check HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

The request will come from the ELB and if you check the details of the request, like from where did the information come it will show the domain name that is [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and it will show the ELB's remote address. The EC2 is never exposed as it is behind the load balance.